# Typeahead.js to search through Users with Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, typeahead.js

I am kinda new to Ruby on Rails. In my application there are users and I want users to search for another users by their name, username, surname etc. I am using typeahead.js from the source https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/ Somehow when I hit enter on the search bar nothing happens. All i got is a question mark like this http://localhost:3000/home? any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

I have this on my **routes.rb**

```
get '/users/typeahead/:query' => 'users#typeahead'
```

**gemfile**

```
gem 'twitter-typeahead-rails'
```

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require typeahead
```

**app/assets/javascripts/users.js**

```
    var onReady = function() {

      // initialize bloodhound engine
      var searchSelector = 'input.typeahead';

      var bloodhound = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function (d) {
          return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,

        // sends ajax request to remote url where %QUERY is user input
        remote: '/users/typeahead/%QUERY',
        limit: 50
      });
      bloodhound.initialize();

      // initialize typeahead widget and hook it up to bloodhound engine
      // #typeahead is just a text input
      $(searchSelector).typeahead(null, {
        displayKey: 'name',
        source: bloodhound.ttAdapter()
      });

      // this is the event that is fired when a user clicks on a suggestion
      $(searchSelector).bind('typeahead:selected', function(event, datum, name) {
        //console.debug('Suggestion clicked:', event, datum, name);
        window.location.href = '/users/' + datum.id;
      });
    };
```

I have **typeahead.js** in the following place

```
vendor/assets/javascripts/typeahead.js
```

My User Model **user.rb**

```
def search_name_like
  search.where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{name_like}%")
end

def search_typeahead
  search.where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{typeahead}%")
end
```

And the controller **users_controller.rb**

```
    # GET /users
      # GET /users.json
      def index
        @search = User.new(search_params)
        @users = search_params.present? ? @search.results : User.all
      end

      # GET /users/typeahead/:query
      def typeahead
        @search  = User.new(typeahead: params[:query])
        render json: @search.results
      end

      private

      def search_params
        params[:user] || {}
      end
```

the view is like **_nav_user.html.erb** layouts/_nav_user.html.erb

```
    div class="form-group"     
       input class="typeahead" type="text"
    /div
```